# not showing error to indicating missing keys in dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying the below code to find missing keys in dictionary. It should function like if the user tries to access a missing key, an error need to popped indicating missing keys.

```
# missing value error
# initializing Dictionary
d = { 'a' : 1 , 'b' : 2 }
 
# trying to output value of absent key
print ("The value associated with 'c' is : ")
print (d['c'])
```

getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "46a9aac96614587f5b794e451a8f4f5f.py", line 9, in 
    print (d['c'])
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Dictionary Check if Key Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498682/python-dictionary-check-if-key-exists)

Comment: your dictionary doesn't have key 'c' , you need to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above example, no key named ‘c’ in the dictionary popped a runtime error. To avoid such conditions, and to make the aware user that a particular key is absent or to pop a default message in that place, we can use get()
get(key,def_val) method is useful when we have to check for the key. If the key is present, the value associated with the key is printed, else the def_value passed in arguments is returned.

eg :

```
country_code = {'India' : '0091',
                'Australia' : '0025',
                'Nepal' : '00977'}

# search dictionary for country code of India
print(country_code.get('India', 'Not Found'))
 
# search dictionary for country code of Japan
print(country_code.get('Japan', 'Not Found'))
```

output:

```
0091
Not Present
```